# Apache2 doesn't work after installing mod-wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, debian, mod-wsgi

I have installed **libapache2-mod-wsgi** on a Debian 8 64 bit server. Whenever I loaded the domain before this install, the default page for apache2 loaded. But after the install it shows *The webpage is not available* error, the same error occurs when there is no internet connection on my PC. I have tried **a2dismod wsgi** to disable it. And then it works again. Can anyone suggest me a workaround?

Comment: Can you please check your apache error-logs and post the corresponding entries here?

Comment: Hey thanks I solved it checking the error log. mod-wsgi was clashing with mod-python. So I disabled mod-python and it's back up again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>>> a2dismod python** did the trick. Mod-wsgi 4.0+ doesn't work with mod-python.